# Multiple dispatches on an a single overloaded operator in S3 (in R)

Tags: r, operator-overloading, multiple-dispatch

I want to overload the '*' (multiplication operator) in R, when using an S3 class.

I see that * is already generic in the system, but I **also** want it "generic2", i.e. dispatching on the second argument.

The use case is as follows:  Say my class is called "Struct".  I want to be able to allow for all three of these cases

```
Struct * Struct 
Struct * Number
Number * Struct
```

However I found that if I allow for dispatching on the second argument, the (already present) dispatching on the first is overridden!

Is there a way that I can do this in S3?

```
# "generic1" already exists for '*'

'*' <- function(x,y){
  UseMethod('*2',y)
}

'*.Struct'<-function(x,y){
  # must both be structs, so dispatch 'normally' if not
  "times(1)"
}

`*2.Struct`<-function(x,y){
  # must both be structs, so dispatch 'normally' if not
  "times(2)"
}
```

Gives me...

```
> struct1 * struct2
[1] "times(2)"
> 2 * struct2
[1] "times(2)"
> struct1 * 2
Error in UseMethod("*2", y) : 
  no applicable method for '*2' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
>
```

If I use this, instead

```
'*' <- function(x,y){ UseMethod('*',x)}
```

Then the dispatch on the first argument works, and the opposite happens:

```
> struct1 * 2
[1] "times(1)"
> struct1 * struct2
[1] "times(1)"
> 2* struct1 
Error in UseMethod("*", x) : 
  no applicable method for '*' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
>
```

So it seems that they're definitely overwriting each other.

Any ideas about how both may coexist peacefully and productively?

Comment: I'd say you should use S4.

Comment: Yeah, probably this could be better handled with S4 class system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check inside the function :

```
'*.Struct'<-function(x,y){
  if(inherits(x,'Struct') && inherits(y,'Struct'))
    "Struct*Struct"
  else if(inherits(y,'Struct'))
    "N*Struct"
  else
    "Struct*N"
}
# N.B.: you don't need to redefine `*`,`*2.Struct` etc
```

e.g. :

```
struct1=structure(5,class='Struct')
struct2=structure(3,class='Struct')

struct1*struct2
# [1] "Struct*Struct"
struct1*2
# [1] "Struct*N"
3*struct2
# [1] "N*Struct"
```

---

As stated [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/groupGeneric) dispatching works on both arguments with the following rule :

> If a method is found for just one argument or the same method is found
>   for both, it is used. If different methods are found, there is a
>   warning about ‘incompatible methods’: in that case or if no method is
>   found for either argument the internal method is used.

So, for example since there's also a `*.difftime` method define, these cases will give odd results with warnings :

```
difftimeObj <- Sys.time()-Sys.time()

struct1*difftimeObj
# [1] 0
# attr(,"units")
# [1] "secs"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "Struct"
# Warning message:
# Incompatible methods ("*.Struct", "*.difftime") for "*" 

difftimeObj*struct2
# Time difference of 0 secs
# Warning message:
# Incompatible methods ("*.difftime", "*.Struct") for "*"
```

while these instead work :

```
struct1*unclass(difftimeObj)
# [1] "Struct*N"
unclass(difftimeObj)*struct2
# [1] "N*Struct"

# skipping dispatching
`*.Struct`(struct1, difftimeObj)
# [1] "Struct*N"
`*.Struct`(difftimeObj, struct2)
# [1] "N*Struct"
```

Comment: Thanks.  That will work for me in THIS case, since Struct happens to be a vector, so multiplication by a Number will be handled by default, but unfortunately I don't think it would work, if I could not rely on the sytem default behaviour, i.e. if I HAD to be able to define the behaviour of "Number * Struct" myself...

Comment: @AlexGian: to be honest, I don't understand your problem... with my example, you have possibly 3 cases, just "unclass" the objects inside one of the case before multiplying if you want the default R behavior...but probably I'm missing something

Comment: I doubt that it's you who doesn't understand.  This is only my second day with R, so I may well be missing something.  I'll mull on it some more, try the unclassing you suggested, and see if I can come up with something.  Thanks anyway.  (BTW, what I was saying, is ¿HOW? will the overloaded operator be triggered, even, if the first argument is a number?  I thought the dispatch was happening because the first arg was a Struct.

Comment: Right, yes, I'd noticed that difftime method define.  It has now somehow been overwritten, I don't see it there any more.  Anyways I removed the
 '*' <- function(x,y) { UseMethod('*', x) }
line, reloaded everything, and now your original code works fine!  I'm not sure where the difftime thingumy has got itself to, but I am happy to proceed as it is now, I'm sure I'll get to grips with the minutiae later.  Many thanks for your detailed help!

Comment: Sure :) Consider also that you can override the whole set of operators (i.e. `>,<,==,+,-,*`...) using `Ops.Struct <- function(){}` check how the function for an example, check how `Ops.difftime` is implemented